# Getting an error while creating a custom function with describe and dtypes

Tags: python, pandas

The aim is to create a custom function in python/pandas on giving an output as dataframe.
I want to have a summary/describe of a dataframe along with dtypes for a given dataframe.

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'nick', 'juli'], 'marks':[99, 98, 95, 90]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index =['rank1', 'rank2', 'rank3', 'rank4']) 
df 

def inspect(data):
    return pd.DataFrame({"Type":data.dtypes,
                         "Describe":data.describe(include='all'),
                        })
```

When i run this function

```
inspect(df)
Output:

        Type    Describe
Name    object  (N, a, m, e)
marks   int64   (m, a, r, k, s)


Desired Ouput:

    count   unique  top freq    mean    std min 25% 50% 75% max   dtypes
Name    4     4     nick    1   NaN     NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   object
marks   4   NaN     NaN NaN     92.5    2.88 90 90 92.5 95 95     int64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas 0.25.0 is necessary transpose and add new column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
def inspect(data):
    return data.describe(include='all').T.assign(Type=data.dtypes)

print (inspect(df))
      count unique   top freq  mean      std  min    25%   50%    75%  max  \
Name      4      4  Jack    1   NaN      NaN  NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN   
marks     4    NaN   NaN  NaN  95.5  4.04145   90  93.75  96.5  98.25   99   

         Type  
Name   object  
marks   int64
```